# ssh-agent isn't loaded when i run command locally

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ubuntu-18.04

I want to deploy an app from my Mac to my ubutun 18.04 server. The problem is that when i go to my server and do a simple command like ssh -T git@bitbucket.org all work fine. It doesn't ask my passphrase etc...
But when I run the command

```
ssh deploy@ipofmyserver 'ssh -T git@bitbucket.org'
```

I've got this error :

> git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).

My ssh key is generated and well inform in my bitbucket account.

I notice that when I connect with ssh deploy@... the user-agent is not started. When I run the command

```
ssh deploy@... 'eval `ssh-agent -s` && ssh-add && ssh -T git@bitbucket.org'
```

It ask me my passphrase and i've got the response that i'm able to connect.
I try to use this solution to use a user-agent already running : https://github.com/wwalker/ssh-find-agent but it doesn't work.

Any solution ?

Comment: `ssh -J deploy@ipfmyserver git@bitbucket.org` would be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try to use this solution to use a user-agent already running : https://github.com/wwalker/ssh-find-agent but it doesn't work.

If, as documented, you tried to use `. ssh-find-agent.sh` in `~/.bashrc` or `~./.zshrc`, that would not work.

The core of your issue (ssh inside ssh) is that the [ssh session would read:

- [`~/.bash_profile`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/332533/7490) in an interactive session (not `.bashrc`)
- nothing in a non interactive session  (`ssh user@server 'a command'`)

You should at least source your `.bash`(`rc` or `_profile`) to trigger the `. ssh-find-agent.sh` and see if it finds your ssh agent (already running, for which the passphrase was already entered)

If you *have to* enter a passphrase, you might need [`expect`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index) as shown at the [end of this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90869/7490).

The [OP jean-max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5846066/jean-max) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63425668/ssh-agent-isnt-loaded-when-i-run-command-locally/63429407#comment112163510_63429407) that sourcing the `.profile` (*not* `.bash_profile`) is enough to make the  `. ssh-find-agent.sh` work.

---

[chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63425668/ssh-agent-isnt-loaded-when-i-run-command-locally?noredirect=1#comment112163601_63425668) the [`ssh -J` "jump host" option](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSH_jump_host), here a dynamic one:

```
ssh -J deploy@ipfmyserver git@bitbucket.org
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'ved source in the .bashrc to trigger the .ssh-find-agent.sh and it doesn't work but when I sources in .profile it works. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: @jean-max I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.